# Converting an array of integers to unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have an array arr=[07,10,11,05].
I actually would want these values to be converted to hex and send it to a function. I know I can convert the values individually to hex like hex(arr[0]), hex(arr[1]) etc. What I have been doing now is, converting the array to 
unicode as arr =[u'07 0a 0b 05'] manually and then sending to the function which serves the purpose for me. But it is too impractical when I have to send hundreds to unicode strings in arr as in

```
arr = [u'a3 06 06 01 00 01 01 00',
u'a3 06 06 02 00 01 02 00',
u'a3 06 06 03 00 01 03 00',
u'a3 06 06 04 00 01 04 00',
u'a3 06 06 05 00 01 05 00',
u'a3 06 06 06 00 01 06 00',
u'a3 06 06 07 00 01 07 00']
```

I am sending this one by one (arr[i]) using a loop. Is there a way I can dynamically convert an array of integers to unicode and send it to an external function which readily accepts such unicode strings?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?: `arr = [hex(i) for i in arr]`, or `arr = [chr(i) for i in arr]`, or if `07` means `g`, then `arr = [chr(i+96) for i in arr]`, or if `07` means `h` then `arr = [chr(i+97) for i in arr]`

Answer (score 0):

Is `' '.join(map(hex,arr))` what you are looking for?

More specifically:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[6,11,23]])

def strip_hexstring(s):
    return s.strip('0x').strip('L')

def format_line(line):
    return u'{}'.format(' '.join(map(strip_hexstring,map(hex,line))))

arr = [format_line(a[i,:]) for i in range(a.shape[0])]
```

You can pad with zeros like in your example, if necessary.